# Efficiently assign bar chart from a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm currently manually creating a `bar chart` from a `pandas` `df`. Is there a more efficient way to read it straight from the `df`?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = ({
    'A' : ['1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','3'],     
    'B' : ['A','B','C','A','B','C','D','A','B','C'],
    'C' : ['John','Carl','Carl','John','Lily','John','Lily','John','Carl','Carl'],         
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (3,3))

Ay = [3]
Ax = [1]

By = [2,1]
Bx = [7,12]

Cy = [1,2]
Cx = [3,8]

Dy = [1]
Dx = [14]

plt.bar(Ax,Ay, label = 'A')
plt.bar(Bx,By, label = 'B')
plt.bar(Cx,Cy, label = 'C')
plt.bar(Dx,Dy, label = 'D')

plt.legend(loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
```

If I manually add in xticks to display the person the intended output is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using `pivot_table`

```
df.assign(A=df.A.astype(int)).pivot_table(index="C", columns="B", values="A",aggfunc='count').rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None,1).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your data in dataframe and plot doesn't match, for example John has matching rows

```
>>> df[df.C == "John"]
   A  B     C
0  1  A  John
3  2  A  John
5  2  C  John
7  3  A  John
>>>
```

Setting the dataframe to the data as in plot.

```
>>> d = ({
...     "A" : [3,1,2,2,1,1],
...     "B" : ["A", "C", "B", "C", "B", "D",],
...     "C" : ["John", "John", "Carl", "Carl", "Lily", "Lily"]
... })
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Use [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to reshape the column and plot.

```
>>> df.pivot(index="C", columns="B", values="A").plot(kind="bar")
```

Comment: Column A represents an event, while Column B represents different functions for that event. So John could be assigned with with different functions for the same event

Comment: When you answer the question , please try to using the data op posted .

Comment: I understand, as I have said in my post I did not know how y values were calculated from the original dataframe.